# How to get the identifier for a folder in Google Drive in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I need to upload a file to a specific folder on Google Drive using my iOS app.  I know the name of the folder, but in order to upload it to a specific folder, I also need to specify the identifier for the folder.  Here is part of my code where I have hard-coded the identifier for the destination folder.  So, my questions is how do I find the identifier of the destination folder programatically.

```
     NSString *mimeType = @"image/png";
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:imageData MIMEType:mimeType];
GTLDriveFile *fileObj = [GTLDriveFile object];
fileObj.title = @"this_is_a_test.png";
GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentRef.identifier = @"0B1Em3SqS0WHrQi15SHB4OHRGd2c";
fileObj.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:parentRef];
```

Answer (score 3):

A Drive list query can be restricted to fetching folders using the query string parameter:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q =  [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title='%@' and trashed=false",
    title];
```

But file and folder titles are not unique in Google Drive, so there may be many folders or files in a user's account with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you also specify how I get the identifier of a folder with a specific name (assume it's unique)?

Comment: @grobbins, could you please explain how to dig out parentId from queryForFilesList callback?

Comment: @ValeriyVan Quite old question but maybe anyone will need it also. To dig out the id: `result.items.firstObject.identifier`. To get the parentID: `result.items.firstObject.parents.firstObject.identifier`. Ofc you should handle which objects, what when there are no results etc.